# How to use fields_for to link multiple models from one form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, belongs-to, nomethoderror, has-one

I am building a registration app. There are three models: `Participant`, `Volunteer_Detail`, and `Student_Detail`. `Participant` `has_one` of the other two models, while they in turn `belongs_to` `Participant`. I am trying to use one form with fields_for to supply data to `Participant` and one of the other models.

I keep getting an error, saying that one of the attributes, intended for `Student_Detail`, is not a defined attribute of `Participant`.

I have looked at several guides on `fields_for` and it seems that there are several ways to define the second model your form is intended for.

The consensus seems to be that it should look like this:

```
         <%= f.fields_for @participant.student_details do |student_detail_field| %>
                    <%= f.label :nationality, 'Nationality:' %> 
                    <%= student_detail_field.text_field :nationality %>
```

However it only seems to show my form when I write :student_details as opposed to @participant.student_details.

Here is my form, showing the top section, and the section where fields_for is include(form is trimmed to save space):

```
                    <%= f.label :first_name, 'First:' %>
                    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

         <%= f.fields_for :student_details do |student_detail_field| %>
                    <%= f.label :nationality, 'Nationality:' %> 
                    <%= student_detail_field.text_field :nationality %>
```

Here is my Participants controller:

class ParticipantsController < ApplicationController
                def new
                @participant= Participant.new
                end

```
            def new2
            @participant= Participant.new
            end

            def create
            @participant = Participant.create(participant_params)
            @participant.save
            if @participant.save
            flash[:success] = "Successfully Registered!"        

            #email notifes admin of new registration
            NotifyMailer.notify_email(@participant).deliver_later

            redirect_to '/signup'
            end
            end

            def edit
            end

            def update
            end

            def show
            end

            def index
            end

            private
            def participant_params
            params.require(:participant).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :gender, :email, :birthdate, :phone, :street_name, :city, :state, :zip, :nationality, :religion, :need_ride, 
            :has_spouse, :spouse_name, :english_level, :expectations, :length_of_stay, :exact_length, :volunteer_id, :matched, :returned_home, :participant_id, :participant_id_id)

            end


            end
```

Here is the server error:

```
    NoMethodError (undefined method `nationality' for #<Participant:0x000000000d039410>
                            Did you mean?  Rational):

                            app/controllers/participants_controller.rb:11:in `create'
                            Rendering C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
                            Rendering C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
                            Rendered C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (3.9ms)
                            Rendering C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
                            Rendered C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
                            Rendering C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
                            Rendered C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
                            Rendered C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (790.6ms)
```

Looking to see if anyone can help clarify what I'm getting wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are couple things that probably can help**

1. How to define **has_one relationship**:

   Following [rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-one-foreign-key), since Participant has_one student_detail, then the student_detail table has to have field participant_id, also volunteer_detail has to have field participant_id

   you can set `participant.rb` (model) to accept nested attributes for student_detail or volunteer_detail (since you said provide one form for those tables)

   ```
   class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_one :student_detail, :dependent => :destroy
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :student_detail,   :allow_destroy => :true
     # that allow_destroy is depend with your software design
     has_one :volunteer_detail, :dependent => :destroy
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :volunteer_detail,   :allow_destroy => :true
   end
   ```
2. How to setup **participant_params** for other tables:

   Here is sample of code that define participant params for accept nested atributes:

   ```
   def participant_params
     params.require(:participant).permit(
       :first_name, :other_participant_field_name, 
       student_detail_attributes: [:participant_id, :other_student_field_name],
       volunteer_detail_attributes: [:participant_id, :other_volunteer_field_name])
     end
   end
   ```

   If you want the content for student record also for `volunteer_detail` you can do in your controller (create method), *my tip for this try to refactor/redesign to minimize data duplication in your system (student and volunteer)*

   ```
   def create
     @participant = Participant.create(participant_params)
     @volunteer_detail = @participant.student_detail
     # this will pass all the content of student detail to volunteer detail
     if @participant.save
       flash[:success] = "Successfully Registered!"        
     end
   end
   ```

To learn more about accept nested attributes I suggest you learn from [railcast 196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) although it seem old but you can learn the concept